# How to set & measure volume in iOS webapp?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

This needs to be pure javascript, no cordova or native code, so that it will run properly in a web app on iOS (eg iOS Chrome/Safari).
We need to be able to adjust the volume that a sound is played at so that it is in the right range for a user.
We also need to be able to know what the system volume of an iOS device is.
As far as we've found, Apple prevents this.

Comment: I would not want my browser to adjust my volume, and I don't think a webpage can force someone to listen to an ad.  The user decides what the right range is for their setting.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp